# PHP - Return Count An Item Appears In Array

Tags: php

I am trying to count how many times Apple appears in this array

```
$fruits = array (
"Apple",
 array("Apple", "Kiwi", "Tomato")
 );
```

Is this a multidimension array? How would I be able to check the total count apple appears?

Comment: Do you want to make it extremely robust regardless of how deep the array is(without flattening) ?

Comment: @Robin - Yes thank you. This lead me to the solution, I first flattened the array then used the count and array filter methods to return me the total times Apple appeared in the new array.

Comment: There is no need of flattening to be honest. It is just extra memory consumption!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to flat the array.

```
$fruits = array (
"Apple",
 array("Apple", "Kiwi", "Tomato")
 );
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($fruits));
foreach($it as $v) {
  $flat_arr[] = $v;
}
```

Then filter items that only have 'Apple':

```
$result_count = count(array_filter($flat_arr, function($item) {
    return substr('Apple', $item) !== false;
}));
```